# Maven with JBoss developer studio 9.x

Tags: maven

I am using Maven 3.3.3 version and JBOSS DEVELOPER STUDIO 9.x .
I am trying to create a maven module. I am getting one error.

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

In command prompt I am getting this.

[image]

Proxy details are as follows, where xxx can be replaced by the username, password , host respectively.

```
 <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>xxx</username>
  <password>xxx</password>
  <host>xxx, 3128</host>
  <port>3128</port> 
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're behind a proxy then please put it into your [%USER_HOME%/.m2/settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

It seems there is no connection from your workstation / server to the maven central due to the proxy settings.

What happens when you try to invoke maven outside JBoss Developer Studio? E.g.

```
mvn archetype:create 
  -DgroupId=test
  -DartifactId=test2
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

Comment: ' It seems there is no connection from your workstation / server to the maven central due to the proxy settings. ' .. ....................You are correct. Net problem. Works fine in my colleagues machine. Thanks

Comment: There is some networking problem (proxy server, network configuration, firewall) on your workstation. Can you download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml from browser?

Comment: In the .m2 directory you have the jars. The settings are in `%MAVEN_HOME%\conf\settings.xml` (where `MAVEN_HOME` can be `M2_HOME`)